# Is this C# SqlDecimal math bug?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement SQL Server [Vardecimal](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508963%28v=sql.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) decompression. Values stored as 3 digits decimals per every 10 bits. But during implementation I found strange behavior of math. Here is simple test I made

```
private SqlDecimal Test() {

  SqlDecimal mantissa = 0;
  SqlDecimal sign = -1;
  byte exponent = 0x20;
  int numDigits = 0;

  // -999999999999999999999999999999999.99999

  for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {

    int temp = 999;

    //equal to mantissa = mantissa * 1000 + temp;
    numDigits += 3;
    int pwr = exponent - (numDigits - 1);
    mantissa += temp * (SqlDecimal)Math.Pow(10, pwr);
  }

  return sign * mantissa;
}
```

First 2 passes are fine, I have

```
999000000000000000000000000000000
999999000000000000000000000000000
```

but third have

```
999999998999999999999980020000000
```

Is it some bug in C# `SqlDecimal` math or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It think it is correct.   If you have a number 0.000000000000000000000001  there are a lot of zeroes in the middle.  The first two results are showing the zeroes in the middle.  The third results is the least significant bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue with how you're constructing the value to add here:

```
mantissa += temp * (SqlDecimal)Math.Pow(10, pwr);
```

The problem starts when `pwr` is 24. You can see this very clearly here:

```
Console.WriteLine((SqlDecimal) Math.Pow(10, 24));
```

The output on my box is:

```
999999999999999980000000
```

Now I don't know *exactly* where that's coming from - but it's simplest to remove the floating point arithmetic entirely. While it may not be efficient, this is a simple way of avoiding the problem:

```
static SqlDecimal PowerOfTen(int power)
{
    // Note: only works for non-negative power values at the moment!
    // (To handle negative input, divide by 10 on each iteration instead.)
    SqlDecimal result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < power; i++)
    {
        result = result * 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you then change the line to:

```
mantissa += temp * PowerOfTen(pwr);
```

then you'll get the results you expect - at least while `pwr` is greater than zero. It should be easy to fix `PowerOfTen` to handle negative values as well though.

Answer (score 1):

## Update

Amending the below method to just work with `Parse` and `ToString` should improve performance for larger numbers (which would be the general use case for these types):

```
public static SqlDecimal ToSqlDecimal(this BigInteger bigint)
{
    return SqlDecimal.Parse(bigint.ToString());
}
```

This trick also works for the `double` returned by the original `Math.Pow` call; so you could just do:

```
SqlDecimal.Parse(string.Format("{0:0}",Math.Pow(10,24)))
```

---

## Original Answer

Obviously [@JonSkeet's answer](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vcgU8A)'s best, as it only involves 24 iterations, vs potentially thousands in my attempt.  However, here's an alternate solution, which may help out in other scenarios where you need to convert large integers (i.e. `System.Numeric.BigInteger`) to `SqlDecimal` / where performance is less of a concern.

[Fiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vcgU8A)

```
//using System.Data.SqlTypes;
//using System.Numerics; //also needs an assembly reference to System.Numerics.dll

public static class BigIntegerExtensions
{
    public static SqlDecimal ToSqlDecimal(this BigInteger bigint)
    {
        SqlDecimal result = 0;
        var longMax = (SqlDecimal)long.MaxValue; //cache the converted value to minimise conversions
        var longMin = (SqlDecimal)long.MinValue;

        while (bigint > long.MaxValue)
        {
            result += longMax;
            bigint -= long.MaxValue;
        }
        while (bigint < long.MinValue)
        {
            result += longMin;
            bigint -= long.MinValue;
        }
        return result + (SqlDecimal)(long)bigint;
    }
}
```

For your above use case, you could use this like so (uses the [BigInteger.Pow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.pow?view=netframework-4.7.2) method):

```
mantissa += temp * BigInteger.Pow(10, pwr).ToSqlDecimal();
```

Comment: I thought about BigInteger too since all numbers gathered in one big integer before applying exponent - placing 128 bit value into 128 bit SqlDecimal container is tricky. Also useful plus actual cast method.

Comment: By the way cast from integer to SqlDecimal can be made by using `SqlDecimal(prec, scale, positive, Int32[])` constructor where Int32[] is actually big integer shifted by scale.

Comment: Nice; I'd not thought to look at the constructors; only the implicit operator and available methods; good shout.

Comment: That was my "option 2" due to SqlDecimal value "1.00" with scale 2 inside is "100" integer in Int32[4] array.